# Can I say "listen for it" and "smell for it"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sense-verbs

I often hear the term to *look for it*:

> "I have studied symbolism in fine arts for years, and now I see symbolism in everything. I just can't stop myself after I learned how to **look for it**."

*Feel for it* is also frequently used:

> "Jimmy was a great guitar player. He didn't even think while playing; his guitar functioned like an extension to his arms. He just had this natural **feel for it**."

It also works for *listening*, although it sounds a bit odd:

> "This city is teeming with songbirds, but their chirps are drowned by the ambiance. You might be able to catch a few seconds here and there if you **listen for it**."

But how about for *smelling*?:

> "My father knows a chef whose sense of smell is so good that he can step into the farmers market and locate the perfect onion by sticking his nose in the air to **smell for it**."

For listening it sounds bit odd, and for smelling it sounds downright wrong to me, but I can't explain why. Are all of the above sentences well-formed English sentences?

Comment: Your ***feel*** example is a completely different usage (the one corresponding to the ***look*** example would be, say, *"He couldn't see where he dropped his plectrum on the dimly-lit stage, so he just had to **feel for it**"*). Note that *to **smell** for something* (to locate it using the sense of smell) isn't normal English. You might do better with *to **sniff** something **out***, but this may have unwanted idiomatic/figurative connotations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference in the *feel* example; I failed to notice the difference. I'll leave it like that so that I don't deprive your comment of its context. *Sniff something out* would also work, and I'm wondering why *smell* cannot be used in this way as *look*, *feel* and possibly *listen* can.

Comment: The idiom is *to follow your nose*:  "he can locate the perfect onion by just following his nose"

Comment: I have encountered "smell for it" used in this way, though I can't recall precisely where. It's not wrong, just uncommon, I think.

Comment: @Jim I've heard "follow your nose" with the alternative meaning of "proceed straight ahead," having nothing to do with smelling or sniffing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words you will hear more often are along the lines of **sniff it out**.

The idiom *sniff out* is defined as (from The Free Dictionary):

> To perceive or detect someone or something by or as if by sniffing:
>   *The dogs sniffed out the trail through the snow.*
>   *The detectives sniffed the plot out and arrested the criminals.*

A similar idiom is **nose out**, having essentially the same meaning in this context. (It can also mean to prevail over someone by a small margin.)

Comment: Because of the strong idiomatic figurative associations (as per your *detectives* example), I think it's actually quite common to sidestep the issue and simply say something like *locate [it] by [sense of] smell*.